Why does this Generic Subscriber throw a runtime exception when the node is run
Why does this caused a runtime exception? The input topic is not even published to.
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <rclcpp/serialization.hpp>
#include <rclcpp/serialized_message.hpp>
#include <std_msgs/msg/string.hpp> // Example message type for publishing

class SerializedMessageSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    SerializedMessageSubscriber()
    : Node("serialized_message_subscriber")
    {
        // Create a subscription to a topic with serialized message data
        subscription_ = this->create_subscription<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::SerializedMessage>>(
            "serialized_topic", 10,
            [this](const std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::SerializedMessage> msg) {
                // Callback function to handle the received serialized message
                RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Received serialized message");

                // Create a deserialized message (we'll assume it's a std_msgs::msg::String for this example)
                try {
                    // Deserialize the message into the appropriate type
                    rclcpp::Serialization<std_msgs::msg::String> serializer;
                    std_msgs::msg::String deserialized_msg;
                    serializer.deserialize_message(msg.get(), &deserialized_msg);

                    // Use the deserialized message
                    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Deserialized message: '%s'", deserialized_msg.data.c_str());
                } catch (const std::exception &e) {
                    RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Failed to deserialize message: %s", e.what());
                }
            });
    }

private:
    rclcpp::Subscription<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::SerializedMessage>>::SharedPtr subscription_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

    // Create the node and spin it to process messages
    rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<SerializedMessageSubscriber>());

    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}

I get the following exception thrown
parallels@ubuntu-linux-22-04-02-desktop:~/projects/ros2_ws$ ros2 run logic serialized 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  this specialization of rclcpp::get_message_type_support_handle() should never be called
[ros2run]: Aborted

